# Get Child Attribute using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a link gallery.

HTML:

```
<div class="link">
    <header>Test Header</header>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

I want to go to the A element's URL when clicking anywhere in the div.

Javascript with JQUERY 3.2.1:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.link").click(function() {
        $url = $this.children("a").attr("href");
        alert($url);
    });
});
```

It doesn't alert the URL

I have also tried:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.link").click(function() {
        $url = $this.find("a:first-child").attr("href");
        alert($url);
    });
});
```

It returns a collection instead of a single element so I tried the following:

```
$function() {
    $("div.link").click(function() {
        $url = $this.find("a");
        alert($url[0].attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Neither approach is working.  I have confirmed the click selector is functioning by testing it with a simple alert("hello");

EDIT: I was using $this instead of $(this).

Comment: Try using: $(this)

Comment: `$this` isn’t defined. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: oh wow.  I cannot believe I made such a stupid mistake.  Of course it is $(this).  I am an idiot.  I have been developing in PHP so much lately it must have corrupted my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to goto the A element's URL when clicking anywhere in the div.

Based on the code you have shared, `$this` seems to be `undefined`

If you just want to fetch the `href` property of the child *anchor tag*, then simply

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr( "href" ); //attr will fetch the attribute of first element in the result of find
});
```

If you want to `click` on the child *anchor tag*, then try using one of the following ways

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    $(this).find("a").first().click();
});
```

or

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    $(this).find("a").click();
});
```

or

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    $(this).find("a").trigger( "click" );
});
```

or if you just want to go the URL

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find("a").attr( "href" );
});
```

Comment: This is correct.  I don't know what I was thinking with $this.  I have no idea.  I am selecting this as the answer in 7 minutes when I can.  Dumb question.

Comment: @Velocibadgery Try using developer-tools of a browser more often (like console, element-inspector) - this kind of issues will become easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `href` attribute when clicking on the div element, you can consider using the selector `$(".nameOfDivClass")`. On the element selected you will bind a function that will get your `href`.

```js
$(".link").on("click", function(){
 console.log($(this).children("a").attr("href"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
    <header>Test Header</header>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your browser's console, you'll have an error saying `$this is not defined`. It should be `$(this)`, in order to turn `this` (the raw HTML element clicked on) into a jQuery object on which you can the run jQuery methods such as .find() and .attr().

Additionally, this version will actually cause the navigation action rather than just alerting the URL:

```
$("div.link").click(function() {
    $(this).find("a").click();
});
```